# What is the difference between (void **)&x and (void *)x?

Tags: c, pointers, cuda, gpgpu, gpu

What is the difference between (void **)&x and (void *)x? I will give you some code, please help me out.

```
float *xd;
int size=width*width*size(float);
cudaMalloc((void **)&x,size); 1
cudaMalloc((void *)x,size);   2
cudaMalloc(&x,size);          3
cudaMalloc(*x,size);          4

cudaFree(xd);
```

I just want to know the difference.

The first parameter of the cudaMalloc() function is the address of a pointer variable that must point to the allocated object after allocation. The address of the pointer variable should be cast to (void **) because the function expects a generic pointer value; the memory allocation function is a generic function that is not restricted to any particular type of objects. This address allows the cudaMalloc() function to write the address of the allocated object into the pointer variable.3 The second parameter of the cudaMalloc() function gives the size of the object to be allocated, in terms of bytes. The usage of this second parameter is consistent with the size parameter of the C malloc() function.

Comment: [C++decl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/c++decl) may be of use here

Comment: It's much the same as the difference between &x and x. Questions like this aren't useful without knowing why you might think that two very different things are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're just about *completely* different.

This:

```
(void **)&x
```

takes the address of `x` and converts it to `void**` (pointer to pointer to `void`).

This:

```
(void *)x
```

takes the *value* of `x` and converts it to `void*`.

They're both pointers, but they point to entirely different locations in memory (unless `x` happens to contain its own address), and they're of different types.

And if you want to show us code, it would be helpful to show us code that actually compiles. Copy-and-paste your actual source code; don't re-type it. You haven't shown us the declaration of `x` (is `xd` a typo for `x`?), and `size(float)` is a syntax error (did you mean `sizeof(float)`?).

Answer (score 3):

To give you a better understanding *why* with `cudaMalloc` you often write `(void**)&var`, consider the following:

`cudaMalloc` allocates a memory on the GPU. The memory type it is referred is `void*` as it does not really care about the data type.

Once we have the address of that memory inside the `cudaMalloc` we just allocated, we need to somehow return it to the caller. But all CUDA API functions are returning error codes (or success code) and any additional returned data has to be passed back by parameter reference.

C language has no pass-by-reference, so you actually need to pass a pointer to a variable where you want the function to store the result. Since you want to store a pointer value, you need to pass a pointer-to-pointer. Hence `void**` type.

If one wanted to encapsulate a malloc in similar way, one would write something like this:

```
void myMalloc(void** ret, size_t size) {
    void* mem = malloc(size);
    *ret = mem;
}
```

Now, if you pass `(void**)&var` to `myMalloc`, the function will be able to overwrite the value of the `var` --- as `ret` will be pointing to `var` variable.

Does this make it clearer?

Comment: But it’s undefined behavior; you need to use a `void*` **temporary**.

Comment: @DavisHerring To what you are refering?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: storing through a pointer produced by `(void**)&var` is undefined behavior (except in the trivial case where `var` actually is of type `void*`).  The way to use `cudaMalloc` is `float *f; {void *v; if(cudaMalloc(&v,n*sizeof*f)) …; f=v;}`.

Comment: For most architectures and most compilers you can cast between `void**` and `T**` (where T is not a function). And for C standard - it is not applicable, because CUDA by definition is beyond the scope of the standard and as such is one big undefined behavior.

Comment: You can do the cast, but the optimizer is allowed to assume that no store occurs through the result (unless it’s cast back to the correct type first).  This question isn’t actually about CUDA except as an example, and there’s no reason to encourage broken idioms even if the concessions to practicality made by a C/CUDA implementation (which isn’t UB just because it’s an extension) happen to not break it (today).